# Using Fitted Model in make_scorer For gridsearchcv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring

I am creating a custom scorer for a gridsearchcv object.  For the customer scorer I need probabilities from two different dataframes, but the model should only be trained on one of the dataframes. The other dataframe is needed to get probabilities.  These probabilities will be used in the scoring function.

I had considered concatenating the dataframes, but there is no ground truth to one of the dataframes.  This would create an issue with passing the y_true.

I had also tried to pass the model to the custom score function, but I got a traceback that the model was not fit.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
def fit(self, X_train, y_train, X_info):
    grid = self._create_grid_search()
    clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()
    score_func = make_scorer(self.make_custom_score, needs_proba=True, clf=clf, X_info=X_info)


    model = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, 
                         param_grid=grid, 
                         scoring=score_func,
                         cv=3)


def make_custom_score(self, y_true, y_score, clf, X_info):
```

I found this question: [SKLearn cross-validation: How to pass info on fold examples to my scorer function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315893/sklearn-cross-validation-how-to-pass-info-on-fold-examples-to-my-scorer-functio)
which seems to be something that might be a possibility.  This approach would seem to be to write a function in the form of scorer(estimator, X, y), but I think this will still have the issue that the model will be trained on all of the data.  Is there any way to pass the estimator to the custom score function to be used by gridsearchcv?

Comment: Is `X_info` the same size as `X_train`?  Can you show what you intend to do with `X_info` (the code in `make_custom_score`)? Since the `X_train` will be divided into train and test inside GridSearchCV, will the same splitting be applied to X_info?

Comment: X_info and the clf would be passed so I can get the probabilities of X_info.  These probabilities will be used in the scoring function.  It is a different dataframe (so not the same size as X_train), and there is no need to split the dataframe, I need all of the probabilities.